# how to insert numeric(10,6) datatype column value in to numeric(8,6) datatype column

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table `TABLEA with COL1 NUMERIC(8,6)` and need to insert a value from second table `TABLEB` which contains a value `123.000000`.I have tried below scenarios.In this case i have to use `NVL` function and `CAST` together

```
SELECT CAST(899.000000 AS NUMERIC(8,6))-- This gives Numeric overflow.  Value does not fit in a numeric(8,6)
```

Tried below as well

```
CAST(NVL(COL1,0) AS NUMERIC(10,6)) -- ERROR:  0 : Numeric value out of range
```

Any insights would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The number you have *cannot* fit into a `numeric(8,6)`, the error is quite clear on that. We can't magically make a quart fit in a pint pot.

Answer (score 1):

An important note:
Decimal/numeric data types in netezza is stored as a floating point value under the covers. Therefore you will not 'waste' any space inside the database if you e.g. go from numeric(7,X) to numeric(14,X) or from numeric(4,X) to numeric(6,X)

Look here for more details on these super low-level data types here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm 
Just note that internally the CPU is working on binary data types (base number 2) and most humans use base-10 numbers to discuss these things. Other (more detailed) explanations of this exists on the web, but that is irrelevant for this point :)

Comment: The precision value does dictate the number of bytes used however. A precision of 9 or less is four bytes, 10 to 18 is 8 bytes and anything 19 or higher is 16 bytes. See [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_data_types_exact_numeric.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks, your link is actually the one I was looking for :). I'll add it to my posting if that's okay with you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NUMERIC(p,s)  | Exact numerical, precision p, scale s
```

In your query precision value is 8 that's why getting over flow error.Actual Precision value is 9.

```
SELECT CAST(899.000000 AS NUMERIC(8,6)
```

I have update your query which is below .

```
SELECT CAST(899.000000 AS NUMERIC(9,6))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44406370/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

### You'll need to change the datatype of `TABLEA.COL1`

Note the following:

```
SELECT CAST(899.00000 AS NUMERIC(8,6)) /*Overflow*/
SELECT CAST(899.00000 AS NUMERIC(8,5)) /*Works*/
SELECT CAST(899.00000 AS NUMERIC(9,6)) /*Works*/
SELECT CAST(99.123456 AS NUMERIC(8,6)) /*Works*/
SELECT CAST(100 AS NUMERIC(8,6)) /*Overflow*/
SELECT CAST(99.9999994 AS NUMERIC(8,6)) /*Works (rounds down to 99.999999)*/
SELECT CAST(99.9999995 AS NUMERIC(8,6)) /*Overflow (rounds up to 100)*/
```

Basically, "(8 - 6) == 2", so `numeric(8, 6)` cannot store any number with more than 2 digits left of the decimal point. I.e. cannot store any number `>= 100`.

---

From [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp)

> ```
> Data type     | Description
> ------------- | -----------
> DECIMAL(p,s)  | Exact numerical, precision p, scale s.
>                 Example: decimal(5,2) is a number that has
>                 3 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal
> NUMERIC(p,s)  | Exact numerical, precision p, scale s. (Same as DECIMAL)
> ```

Comment: I am not supposed to change the TableA structure, so is there any way that we can insert in to TableA.? wondering!

Comment: @Samah Do you understand the problem you're facing? If you try to store `123` in a column where the ***biggest possible*** value is `99.999999`, what do you expect to get back when you later read the value back out of the column? Note that getting `123` is ***NOT possible!***

Comment: Yes, i understand.just thought of checking if any possibility is there which i might be missing! Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: @Samah If you're not supposed to change the `TableA` structure, then presumably that means whoever specified the table considered values such as `100`, `123` to be _invalid_ for `Col1`? If so, then perhaps you should rather think in terms of what you do with rows that have invalid data instead of how to store an invalid value? E.g. Perhaps you shouldn't insert the row at all and rather log an error elsewhere. Or insert the row with all the _valid_ values you can, and set `Col1 = NULL`.